# How to Encrypt a Folder Using C++?

Tags: c++, encryption

I'm creating a program uysing `c++` that relies off sensitive information contained within a folder located on my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop. I need some way to protect this information.

Essentially I have two buttons setup on my application. One to encrypt the folder and one to decrypt the folder. However, I have no experience with encryption and don't even know if you can encrypt a folder itself. Most tutorials I have found only talk about encrypting text. A friend recommended using AES encrytpion, but again, I can only find tutorials that show how to encrypt text.

Does anyone know of any way to protect these folders? They contain a large amount of images (.bmp and .png file types) concerning patient information along with a few text files. Obviously the quickest method would be best, as long as they aren't easily accessible without pressing the buttons.

Comment: You cannot arbitrarily encrypt folders, if you have sensitive information, save them in an encrypted FILE.

Comment: zip/tar the folder and encrypt that

Answer (score 4):

Encryption is not some magic wand one can waive over some data, and encrypt it. If your application has a button that automatically "decrypts" the data, it means that anyone else can do it as well. For this button to work as you described, your application must logically know everything that's needed to decrypt the data. If so, a determined attacker can simply obtain a copy of your application, debug it, figure out how it decrypts the data, and game over.

At the very minimum, a passphrase will be required in order to decrypt the data; so that the application alone is not sufficient to effect encryption and decryption.

As far as the actual technology goes, the two primary software libraries on Linux that provide generic encryption facilities are OpenSSL and GnuTLS. Both provide comparable implementations of all standard symmetric and asymetric cipher-suites.

I believe that GnuTLS is a better API, and that's what I recommend. The design of GnuTLS's C API naturally lends itself to a light C++ OO wrapper facade. The GnuTLS library provides extensive documentation, so your first step is to read through the documentation; at which point you should have all sufficient information to implement encryption in your application.

Comment: +1 for "encryption is not a magic wand". If @Jacob doesn't understand how it works, then he will end up not solving the problem (but looking like he has).

Comment: No I completly agree. I have no experience with this information and his comment was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Just a simple point.

You are going to have to make a blob, which you someway mount as a filesystem.  You are also going to have to decide how to control access to that filesystem while people are using it. Also how people are going to synchronize access.  Do it wrong and two people will write to the same area at the same time and create something that no one will ever decrypt!

Look at the source code for dm-crypt and TrueCrypt, but if you want to limit access beyond the permission system that your OS supports you may find yourself way in over your head.

Answer (score 1):

you need build private filesystem,so every file operator must pass you application. you can encrypt the file contain to user.